# Eliminar cero a la derecha de numero decimal contenido en un string en C#

Tags: c#

Recibo en una variable de tipo string el siguiente numero decimal:

```
var1 = "2.70"
```

en caso que el ultimo decimal sea 0 se ignore y se convierta ese string como

```
var1 = "2.7"
```

Otros ejemplos:

```
var1 = "2.00" deberia ser var1 = "2"
var1 = "3.40" deberia ser var1 = "3.4"
var1 = "7.52" deberia ser var1 = "7.52"
```

Parece que hay una funcion que se llama Normalize() pero la estoy usando y no funciona.

```
decimal.Parse(var1).Normalize().ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Utilizando `.ToString("0.########")`

Donde la cantidad de `#` indicará la cantidad máxima de número decimales significativos

```
   decimal.Parse("2,00").ToString("0.########"); // 2
   decimal.Parse("3,40").ToString("0.########"); // 3,4
   decimal.Parse("7,52").ToString("0.########"); // 7,52
```

2.- Utilizando `TrimEnd`

Se elimina cualquier carácter a la derecha, en tu caso el cero.

```
  "2.00".TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.'); // 2
  "3.40".TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.'); // 3.4
  "7.52".TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');  // 7.52
```

Tienes que usarlo 2 veces, la segunda para eliminar el punto en los casos que se requiera, por ejemplo con `2.00`

Comment: ok pero puede ser que alguna vez el formato pueda venir con una coma en lugar de un punto dependiendo del lugar.

Comment: @Popularfan Añadí otra opción más adecuada, pero lo que indicas es sobre el punto o la coma es irrelevante para tu pregunta, si tu configuración regional tiene la `coma` como separador decimal y tu colocas un string con un punto, sencillamente ese no es número decimal (y si fuera al contrario, lo mismo), y en todo caso el separador siempre lo puedes obtener con `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`

Comment: Ok me parece perfecto